# How to draw capital alphabet from dot matrix display?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How can I draw all alphabet in capital mode with python `tkinter`?
Is using canvas polygon helpful? Something like this for `A`:

```
w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height).pack()
points = [100,0, 0, 100, 200,100]
w.create_polygon(points, outline=python_green, fill='yellow', width=3)
```

And how can I create a simple led dot matrix display with python tkinter or other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the capital alphabet, you could use a very large font to write the capital letters (I don't see why you want to draw them):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas

master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, bg="white", width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(50,50, text="A", fill="red", font="Arial 100")

master.mainloop()
```

For the led dot matrix display, you could do something like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import numpy as np

dot_matrix = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
                       [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, bg="black", width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

def display_matrix(matrix):
    h,l = matrix.shape
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(l):
            if matrix[i,j]:
                canvas.create_oval(5 + 12*j , 5 + 12*i, 15 + 12*j, 15 + 12*i, fill="red")

display_matrix(dot_matrix)

master.mainloop()
```

[image]